# Determining whether HTML contains text using BS4 in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape wikipedia's COVID-19 data chart for the US (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data/United_States_medical_cases), and I am running into trouble with determining whether an HTML element contains text or not. I have tried using

```
element.text is not None
```

as an if conditional, but that simply allows the HTML element to put out nothing.

```
element.text != ''
```

has the same result. Is there anything else I could check for?
Here is all my code

```
def getCases(page):
    cases = []
    firstCaseChild = page.find(title='January 21, 2020')
    firstCaseChild2 = firstCaseChild.find_parent('th')
    row = 0
    column = 0
    firstRow = []
    for case in firstCaseChild2.find_next_siblings('td'):
        if column == 55:
            break
        if case.text is not None:
            firstRow.append(case.text)
            column = column+1
            print(case.text)
        else:
            firstRow.append('0')
            column = column+1
            print('0')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution, without using `pandas`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data/United_States_medical_cases'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.tbody.select('tr:has(td)'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
    tds = [int(td) if td else 0 for td in tds]  # replace empty text '' with 0
    print(('{:>5}'*len(tds)).format(*tds))
```

Prints:

```
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    5    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    7    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    2    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    5    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    5    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    1   12    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    9    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    8    2    0    0    0    0    1    0    0   31    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    4    0    0    0    0    0    1    3    0    0    1   11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    1   11    6    1    0    0    0    1    0    1   10    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    3    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    5    0    0    0    2   22    2    1    0    0    0    0    0
    0    2    8    0    0    0    0    0    0    4    0   22    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    4    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    5    0    0    0    0   45    2    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0   26    0    1    0    0    0    2    7    0   34    0    3    1    2    0    0    1    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    4    4    3    0    0    0    4    2    4    1    0    1    1    0   15    2    0    2    2   17    2    0    1    0    0    0    0
    0    0   19    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   26    0    5    4    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    0    0    1    0    0    2    6    2    1    0    5    1    1    1    3    0    1    3    0   13    0    0    0    5   36    4    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    1   24    5    0    0    0    0    1    1    1  105    0    5    8    4    0    2    1    0    0    2    1    1    5    1    0    0    9    5    2    2    0    0    2    3    4    4    0    0    0    0   51    1    0    1    4   31    2    2    0    0    0    0    0
    0    3   20   17    0    0    1    4    0    4    2   99    1    1    6    2    0    0    2    0    1    0    0    0    3    3    0    1    3    9    0   10    1    1    1    2    4    0    0    1    5    1    3    3    0    0    8   43    4    0    0    0    0    0    0
    1    0   21   15    0    0    0    2    0    5    1   91    0    2    7    0    4   10    4    1    0    5    1    1    0    2    0    5   18   11    3    6    0    7    2    9    2    8    0    3    0    3   13    3    1    1    6  112    6    0    1    0    0    0    0
    0    0   49   28    0    1    3    4    6    6    4  111    1    1   14    3    1   13    5    2    0    4    8    1    1   11    6    6   33    0    3   17    5    0    1    8   16   13    0    5    0    0   15    5    2    1   21   93   19   15    0    0    0    3    1

...and so on.
```

Comment: I didn't use your answer exactly, but I think the strip attribute was what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep away from scraping large tables like this with beautifulsoup.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data/United_States_medical_cases')
```

Each table is within a list of dataframes for example `df[0]` prints the first table you see on wikipedia `df[0]`. Nan refers to missing data.

You can set the value for NaN using pandas. Here we set it to 0.

```
df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why would you not want to use beautifulsoup for large tables?

Comment: It's just messy and often requires lots of for loops, particulary since here there's lots of missing data. It'll be a nightmare to find the cells with actual numbers in them. The code above is concise and pandas is a great package for manipulating data.